# Reversing the content of a set in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I want to reverse the contents of a `std::set`(Not just iterating theough it in reverse, but reversing the contents iteslf). I found that `std::set` takes the compare as a function object for its constructor. Hence I came up with the following code to do the same:

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;
struct Comparator
{
    Comparator(bool g) : m_g(g){}
     bool operator()(int i1, int i2) const
    {
        if(m_g)
        {
            return i1>i2;
        }
        return i1<i2;
    }
        bool m_g;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Comparator l(false);
    set<int,Comparator> a(l);
    a.insert(1);
    a.insert(2);
    a.insert(3);
    Comparator g(true);
    set<int,Comparator> b(g);
    copy(a.begin(), a.end(), inserter(b, b.begin()));
    a = b;
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work in VC9. But is this code correct? My doubt arises due to the fact my `Comparator` has state associated with it. Are comparators are allowed to have states?

Comment: I can't see why not, provided you don't change the state mid-comparison. You should make the bool private to protect this, and if you're worried about style then probably use a class not a struct in the first place - a comparitor feels more like a class than a struct to me.

Comment: Normally, you'd use different comparator types. is it important for y our use case that the set has the same type in both cases?

Comment: templating the sort order on the Comparator will be marginally faster as the compiler will know the boolean constant at compile-time and actually skip a branch at runtime.

Comment: @Jalf: yes, I need to use the same object. All my other code accesses this set so I can't use different comparator types.

Comment: @Will: I know which comparator to use only at runtime.. hence all this round about way of doing it.

Comment: why should you want to do this? a `set` either contains a value or it doesn't. wouldn't it be better to use another container type?

Comment: I'm curious as to how exactly you need to use this. I have trouble thinking up a situation where I couldn't just use the same exact set, but only modify my algorithm to suit the desired order.

Comment: @Rup: to ensure that the state is not changed after the object is created, it is better to make it `const` than `private`

Comment: @Kerrek SB: the problem is I need to either iterate forward or reverse depending on certain condition at run time. This iteration code is there in many places. So I thought it may be simpler instead to reverse the set itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's legal. Consider that if the comparator was not allowed to have state, there would be no point in allowing you to pass a comparator as a constructor parameter. :)

As long as the comparator provides a strict weak ordering, it's fine (which, among other things, means that it has to be consistent. You can't change the state of it halfway through, so that it orders elements differently)

Comment: Which is why there is no way for you to access the comparator which the set itself uses.  (You can get a copy of it by using `std::set<>::key_comp()`, but this returns by value, so you only get a copy to play with.)

Answer (score 5):

It's fine, but it's needlessly complex.

You can just use `std::less` (the default value for that template parameter!) or `std::greater` from the standard library. They are provided by `<functional>`.

Comment: But then the type will not be same i.e. for first one the type would be `std::set<int,lesser<int> >` and for the second once `std::set<int, greater<int> >`. I want the types to be same.

Comment: "I want the types to be the same" for what purpose? You're going to store Comparators in a container? o_O

Answer (score 2):

A more generic solution. boost::assign and c++11 just for convenience (and the funny *auto reverse*)

```
    # include <iostream>
# include <set>
# include <boost/assign.hpp>


using namespace boost::assign;

template <typename CL , typename Pred>
struct revPred {
    revPred (Pred pred) : pred_(pred) {}
bool operator()(const CL & a, const CL& b)
{
 return pred_(b,a);
 }
Pred pred_;
};

template <typename CL , typename Pred, typename alloc>
inline
std::set<CL,revPred<CL,Pred>,alloc> reverseSet(const std::set<CL,Pred,alloc> & set) {
    std::set<CL,revPred<CL,Pred>,alloc> res(revPred<CL,Pred>(set.key_comp()));
    std::copy(set.begin(), set.end(), std::inserter(res, res.begin())); 
    return res;
    }

int main()
{
 std::set<int> s; s += 0 , 1 , 2 , 3;
 std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [](int x) { std::cout << x << " "; }); 
 std::cout << std::endl;
 auto reverse = reverseSet(s);
 std::for_each(reverse.begin(), reverse.end(), [](int x) { std::cout << x << " "; }); 
 std::cout << std::endl;
 return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

And there is nothing wrong with comparators having state.

Answer (score 1):

This is ok since your comparison doesn't change dynamically and it does provide strict weak ordering.

However, if you're doing this so that the type of the set is the same even when the order changes, I might suggest an alternate idea. Instead of this comparison, you use two different set types with `std::less` and `std::greater` and use an iterator interface like the standard library does, rather than a container interface that depends on all the template parameters.

And finally as noted in the answer from @parapura rajkumar you should use the iterator pair constructor rather than `std::copy`:

```
// Assuming my other comments don't apply, modify as needed if they do:
Comparator g(true);
set<int, Comparator> b(a.rbegin(), a.rend(), g);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide a function object which maintains state. Just use a normal function and it should do the job. Pls. don't mind for the use of lambda. Used as a short cut to do the printing.

```
typedef bool (*Cmp)(int x, int y);

bool Compare(int x, int y)
{
    return x < y;
}


bool CompareR(int x , int y)
{
    return !Compare(x, y);
}

 void SetReverse()
{

    std::set<int, Cmp> s1(Compare);

    s1.insert(1);
    s1.insert(3);
    s1.insert(2);
    s1.insert(4);

    std::for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), [](int x) { std::cout << x << "\n"; });

    std::set<int, Cmp> s2(CompareR);

    s2.insert(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    std::for_each(s2.begin(), s2.end(), [](int x) { std::cout << x << "\n"; });

          s1 = s2;

}
```

Comment: The reason why people prefer to use function objects instead of functions is better performance -- you can't inline an indirect call.

Comment: jagansai, i think your answer is wrong because !compare will give x >= y, which is not weak strict ordering.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large enough set you have already paid the O(NlogN) penalty to make a balanced binary tree. A blind insert into the destination set, you will have to pay the penalty again.

Consider using one of these insert overload.

```
 void insert ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last );
 iterator insert ( iterator position, const value_type& x );
```

The range insert has linear complexity if [ first , last ) are sorted already.